# How to set half hour and 45-minute time zones without worrying about DST changes in Linux?

Tags: linux, timezone, centos7, zoneinfo, tzdata

Currently I am setting time zone GMT+5 on my Linux CentOS 7 machine by linking `/etc/localtime` to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT-5.`

I want to create a zone info file for example `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT-5:30` that enables me to set the current timezone to GMT+5:30 **without having to worry about DST changes**.

I am aware that I could link `/etc/localtime` to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata` for example but then I will have to worry about DST changes even if it may not be implemented in the mean time.

Also I am aware of `TZ=GMT+5:30; export $TZ` but I am worried that this approach backfire for some reason in the future.

Comment: What do you mean "to worry about DST changes"?  DST doesn't apply in `Asia/Kolkata` presently.  Do you mean "if it ever does in the future, I don't want to observe it?"  If so - why ever would you want to make such a supposition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use $TZ variable, you may want to create your own timezone file.

You need create a text file (say MyZone.zic) with

```
Zone MyZone 5:30 - GMT-5:30
```

then run

```
zic -d <desired_folder> MyZone.zic
```

then link compiled file to /etc/localtime